Has Western philosophy been historically overall scientifically realist?
Has Western philosophy been historically overall scientifically realist?
This article (Ladyman 2018) points that there is often a back and forth movement between scientific realism and anti-realism, but it concerns the 20th century.
Western philosophy in Ancient Greece was marked by Aristotle who was a realist, then Western philosophy dropped seriously until the Middle Ages, which was heavily Aristotelian, and then there was the Renaissance, the Enlightenment, and the 19th century which in my impression are hardly deemed scientifically anti-realist.
During the Enlightenment, the empiricists Hume and Berkeley defended a kind of skepticism, but skepticism doesn’t appear to me equivalent to scientific anti-realism.
References:
Ladyman, J. (2018). Scientific realism again. Spontaneous Generations: A Journal for the History and Philosophy of Science, 9(1), 99-107.

It is difficult to speak of Scientific Realism before modern science... having said that, modern science (Galileo, Descartes, Newton) was obviously realist regarding unobservable (atoms,...) and therefore Cartesianism, Epiricism (Locke), etc were so. For ancient philosophy, Aristotle was a realist and he were also a scientist (empirically minded) at least wrt what we today call life sciences.

But you are right: George Berkeley was not a "realist" for sure.

There is a reason Ladyman restricts to the 20-th century. Scientific realism/anti-realism labels are recent creations and applying them to older philosophers is ahistorical and misleading. Aristotle's idea of science was very different from the current one, as was Epicurus's or Hume's or Hegel's or Mill's or even Husserl's. The same goes for realism. Anti-realism as currently understood was only formulated by Dummett in 1963 as an extension of intuitionism beyond mathematics. No wonder you are experiencing difficulties with classifying Hume and Berkeley who never heard of that.

When someone calls themselves a realist I get worried. If anyone called themselves an anti-realist, it would be really scary. If no one would call themselves these things, then they seem to be labels used by opponents. (I take realism to assert that there are "facts of the matter" about something, and anti-realism to deny that)

@ScottRowe - correct... but there is a sort of "naif realism" that wins: are we "anti-realist" about our bank account? It is only an abstraction. And yes, "facts of the matter" exist and are relevant.
